# Login with Apple Id in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

[Here is my login page, actually it should login, but I got error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEsVK.png)
I included sign in capabilities in XCODE

[Xcode configurations all set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiP5o.png)

**
Error Message I got : Unhandled Exception: SignInWithAppleAuthorizationError(AuthorizationErrorCode.canceled, The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1001.))**

```
           child: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                final credential =
                    await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
                  scopes: [
                    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
                    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
                  ],
                );
                print(credential);
                context.read<SignInBloc>().add(
                      SignInEvent.signInWithApple(
                        appleToken: credential.authorizationCode,
                      ),
                    );
              },
```

Above is my function to sign in with Apple Id

Answer (score 0):

App Identifier create to "Sign in with Apple" checkbox selection

like that
[image]